# File.Create taking wrong path name

Tags: c#

I have used this before in Windows XP and VS2008 and never got this error now using VS 2012 and windows 8.

This is my simple code to create a file in c drive is giving exception

```
string path = @"C\SaveValues.txt";
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    using (File.Create(path))
    {
    }
}
```

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\C\SaveValues.txt'.

What is this error referring to?

Comment: There's no colon in your string. It should be `string path = @"C:\SaveValues.txt";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to

`string path=@"C:\SaveValues.txt";` (mainly look at **C:** )